# JSONObject not giving expected results

Tags: java, json

I wrote a code of java which adds the data present in array to an existing json file.

This is my code

```
public static void writeInJsonFile() {
  for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) { 
     String path = list[i][0];
     String id = list[i][2];
     String value = list[i][1];
     
     JSONObject root = mapper.readValue(new File(path), JSONObject.class);
     JSONObject valueJson = new JSONObject();
     valueJson.put("value", value);
     JSONObject idJson = new JSONObject();
     idJson.put("id", valueJson);
     root.put("system", idJson);

     FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path);
     writer.write(String.valueOf(root));
     writer.close();
  }
}
```

List<List> list = [["FileName1","Value1","Id1"],[],[],[]...]
It is writing the code at required path, but not appending it. Previous data gets deleted.

Expected Results

```
FileName1.json

{
  "system" : {
     id1 : {
       "value" : value
     },
     id3 : {
       "value" : value3
     },
     id2 : {
       "value" : value2
     }
  }
}

FileName2.json
{
  "system" : {
      id4 : {
         "value" : value4
       },
       id6 : {
         "value" : value6
       }
   }
}
```

Actual Results

```
FileName1.json

{
  "system" : {
     id2 : {
       "value" : value2
     }
}

FileName2.json
{
  "system" : {
     id6 : {
       "value" : value6
     }
}
```

How should i solve this problem ??

Comment: the code as you posted it will not compile, let alone reach that output. You can't call "size()" on a 2D array, that method doesn't exist.

Comment: Its just a small part of the code not the whole code, and I mentioned at the bottom it is a list just for clarification. e.g. list<list<String>>.

Comment: what you mentioned (copy paste): "list is a 2d array"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't collecting your `JSONObject idJson = new JSONObject();` before trying to add a new value into it. So each time you open the file, you "erase" the old content.

You can do, subject to the existence of the "system" field (Make sure to check it first).

```java
JSONObject idJson = root.getJSONObject("system");
```